# Preference grouping without title

Tags: android, material-design, android-preferences

In the [Android Settings](https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-settings.html#grouping-settings) section of the Material Design Guidelines, it mentions that section titles are optional for preference groupings, and in the image, the last section shows a grouping without a title but with a divider between groupings.

However, I am not able to implement this properly. If I use a `PreferenceCategory` with no title set, there is a blank space where the title would be. I can't just throw in a `View` in a `PreferenceScreen` to a draw a divider, and the promising looking `PreferenceGroup` is abstract or otherwise not able to be used.

So, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the divider using `app:allowDividerAbove="true"` or `app:allowDividerBelow="true"` as per your need. Using `PreferenceCategory` tag is not needed as these attributes can be set in any level of preference hierarchy.